# filename passed to chrome.downloads.download API is ignored

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to initiate a file download in a Chrome extension's background js using the `chrome.downloads.download` API:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (arg) {
    chrome.downloads.download({
      url: arg[0],
      filename: arg[1] + ".jpg",
      conflictAction: "uniquify",
      saveAs: false
    });
  });
```

However the `filename` being specified isn't respected - the original file name is being used instead.

I've tested the same script on Firefox and it's working as expected there, but not Chrome.

I know there's also the `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename` event that I can register a listener to and override the filename from there, but it doesn't fit my use case since the file name I'd like to use is passed in to the `onMessage` listener.

Not sure if there's anything obvious that I missed. Thanks!

**** Update ****

As I later realized, the issue may be due to some other mandatory Chrome extension that's also present since I'm using a corp laptop.

Comment: The only obvious thing is that arg[1] is an invalid file name. Use devtools or console.log to debug the code. The documentation says 'Absolute paths, empty paths, and paths containing back-references ".." will cause an error.' Another idea is that Chrome rejects extensions that don't match file's MIME or it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm thanks for the quick response! Yeah I've made sure `arg[1]` is nothing crazy - it's simply a file name string, there's no runtime error thrown, and MIME of the file downloaded matches (jpeg image). The fact that it works just fine on Firefox made it so much confusing.

Comment: @JianxinGao any chance you can elaborate on your update? I’m seeing an issue where some folks are encountering this, but I can’t recreate it on my own computer.

Comment: @MrColes Ohh I think what happened in my case is I'm using my work laptop and that there are several chrome extensions mandatorily installed by enterprise policy and they (or maybe just one of them) probably interfered.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It worked when I tried the extension in a different chrome profile with only a few extensions installed. But still, I want it to work on the default profile and looking for a way to force that filename.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is a conflict if another extension is using the `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename` listener.

See this bug for more details, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=579563

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `console.log(typeof arg[1]);` before the chrome.downloads.download API call to confirm it is a string. You could also try using a template literal to create the file name.

```
filename: `${arg[1]}.jpg`,
```